# Cannot autowire main's @Configuration's @Bean into a test @Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

The setup may look weird, because it's a code from a commons module within a multimodule project, so it has no Application in main, but it has in test in order to test the reusable components. It is like:

/src/main/java/my.domain.mypackage.ApplicationConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public MyService myService(){
       return MyService();
   }
}
```

/src/test/java/TestApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {}
```

/src/test/java/my.domain.util.TestHelper.java

```
@Component
public class TestHelper {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
}
```

/src/test/java/my.domain.mypackage.MyTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestHelper testHelper;

    @Test
    public void test(){
       //Do something with testHelper
    }
}
```

What happens is that when the test runs it tries to instantiate TestHelper, and for some reason, some of the dependencies from ApplicationConfiguration are not yet available (No qualifying bean of type MyService on TestHelper).

What can it be the reason? I already tried using @Import, @DependsOn, but it does not work and furthermore I am sure it is either a bug or a fundamental error in my design

Comment: try annotating ApplicationConfiguration with @Configuration

Comment: I am sorry, it was a typo, now fixed in the example

Comment: It isn't customary to have a separate `@SpringBootApplication` in your test classpath. What's your reason for doing that? (Note also: Constructor injection is better than field injection for your beans, and if you don't have any "interesting" logic you can just say `@Import(MyService.class)` instead of writing an `@Bean` method.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes, this is likely a culprit.  Delete this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add @Configuration annotation on the top of ApplicationConfiguration.java class.

Comment: I am sorry, it was a typo in my sample code, now corrected. My actual Configuration is correctly annotated.